# Error Code: 1215. --Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, foreign-collection

```
create database university;
use university;

create table department
    (dept_name varchar(20),
     building  varchar(15),
     budget    numeric(12,2),
     primary key(dept_name));

create table course 
    (course_id   varchar(7),
     title       varchar(50),
     dept_name   varchar(20),
     credits     numeric(2,0),
     primary key(course_id),
     foreign key(dept_name) references department);
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed specifying the target column of the `department` table

```
foreign key(dept_name) references department(dept_name));
```

Comment: again the same error.

Comment: No, it works: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70940b/1

Comment: foreign key(dept_name) references department(dept_name)):
Cannot find an index in the referenced table where the
referenced columns appear as the first columns, or column types
in the table and the referenced table do not match for constraint.
Note that the internal storage type of ENUM and SET changed in
tables created with >= InnoDB-4.1.12, and such columns in old tables
cannot be referenced by such columns in new tables.
Please refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html for correct foreign key definition.

Comment: You should delete the tables and recreate them. Maybe there went something wrong. But generally the code works like I posted it. See the link in the SQLFiddle.

Comment: ooh now it worked, thank you very much